# What is unit testing and how do you do it?

Tags: unit-testing

#### Exact duplicate of many posts:

[What is unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing)
 [What Makes a Good Unit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400/what-makes-a-good-unit-test)
 [New to Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580960/new-to-unit-testing)
 [Unit Testing - definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633053/unit-testing-definitions)
 [Learning Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135651/learning-unit-testing)
 [How to properly mock and unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476540/how-to-properly-mock-and-unit-test)
 [Unit Testing: Beginner Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473561/unit-testing-beginner-questions)
 [And many more ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing)
 Also, Google for [site:stackoverflow.com "how do you" unit-test](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&c2coff=1&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22how+do+you%22+unit-test&btnG=Search)

I have read some questions on unit testing, but I don't exactly know WHAT it is or how you do it. I was hoping if someone can tell me the following:

- What exactly IS unit testing? Is it built into code or run as separate programs? Or something else?
- How do you do it?
- When should it be done? Are there times or projects not to do it? Is everything unit-testable?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate.  Similar, but not the same question, as the postsmentioned.

Comment: @Eddie, Where is the first question answered?  I can't seem to find where.

Comment: This discusses the age old question WHAT to test. https://earnestengineer.blogspot.com/2018/03/unit-testing-what-to-test.html

Comment: https://onlyfullstack.blogspot.com/2019/02/what-is-unit-testing.html

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Unit testing involves breaking your program into pieces, and subjecting each piece to a series of tests.

Usually tests are run as separate programs, but the method of testing varies, depending on the language, and type of software (GUI, command-line, library).

Most languages have [unit testing frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks), you should look into one for yours.

Tests are usually run periodically, often after every change to the source code. The more often the better, because the sooner you will catch problems.

Comment: There's a little bit of why missing for me, which is by breaking your program into pieces you can attempt to run an exhaustive examination of your program's capabilities.  So then you *know* it works and therefore write fewer bugs as well as fixing bugs with greater speed.

Comment: Agreed. In addition they protect from regressions, if you fix tests at the same time as bugs (as you should).

Answer (score 165):

### What is unit testing?

Unit testing simply verifies that individual units of code (mostly functions) work as expected. Usually you write the test cases yourself, but some can be automatically generated.

The output from a test can be as simple as a console output, to a "[green light](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.4.8)" in a GUI such as [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=home), or a different language-specific framework.

Performing unit tests is designed to be simple, generally the tests are written in the form of functions that will determine whether a returned value equals the value you were expecting when you wrote the function (or the value you *will expect* when you *eventually* write it - this is called [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Driven_Development) when you write the tests first).

### How do you perform unit tests?

Imagine a very simple function that you would like to test:

```
int CombineNumbers(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

The unit test code would look something like this:

```
void TestCombineNumbers() {
    Assert.IsEqual(CombineNumbers(5, 10), 15); // Assert is an object that is part of your test framework
    Assert.IsEqual(CombineNumbers(1000, -100), 900);
}
```

When you run the tests, you will be informed that these tests have passed. Now that you've built and run the tests, you know that this particular function, or unit, will perform as you expect.

Now imagine another developer comes along and changes the `CombineNumbers()` function for performance, or some other reason:

```
int CombineNumbers(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

When the developer runs the tests that you have created for this very simple function, they will see that the first `Assert` fails, and they now know that the build is broken.

### When should you perform unit tests?

They should be done as often as possible. When you are performing tests as part of the development process, your code is automatically going to be designed better than if you just wrote the functions and then moved on. Also, concepts such as [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) are going to evolve naturally into your code.

The most obvious benefit is knowing down the road that when a change is made, no other individual units of code were affected by it if they all pass the tests.

Answer (score 15):

**What...**

A methodology for automaticaly testing code against a battery of tests, designed to enforce desired outcomes and manage change.

A "unit" in this sense is the smallest atomic component of the code that makes sense to test, typically a method of some class for example. Part of this process is building up stub objects (or "mocks") which allow you to work with a unit as an independant object.

**How...**

Almost always, the process of unit-testing is built into an IDE (or through extensions) such that it executes the tests with every compile. A number of frameworks exist for assisting the creation of unit tests (and indeed mock objcts), often named *foo*Unit (cf. jUnit, xUnit, nUnit). These frameworks provide a formalised way to create tests.

As a process, test driven development (TDD) is often the motivation for unit testing (but unit testing does not require TDD) which supposes that the tests are a part of the spec definition, and therefore requires that they are written first, with code only written to "solve" these tests.

**When...**

*Almost* always. Very small, throwaway projects may not be worth it, but only if you're quite sure they really are throwaway. In theory every object orientated program is unit testable, but some design pattrns make this difficult. Notoriously, the singleton pattern is problematic, where conversely dependancy injection frameworks are very much unit testing oriented.

Answer (score 6):

What is unittesting? It is tricky to define. On a technical level, you build functions that call functions in your codebase and validate the results. Basically, you get a bunch of things like "assert(5+3) == 8", just more complicated (as in DataLayer(MockDatabase()).getUser().name == "Dilbert"). 
On a tool-view-level, you add an automated, project-specific check if everything still works like you assumed things worked. This is very, very helpful if you refactor and if you implement complicated algorithms. 
The result generally is a bunch of documentation and a lot less bugs, because the behaviour of the code is pinned down.

I build test cases for all the edge cases and run them similar to the workings of a generational garbage collector. While I implement a class, I only run the test cases that involve the class. Once I am done with working on that class, I run all unittests in order to see if everything still works.

You should test as much as possible, as long as the test code is easy enough to stay untested. Given that, no, not everything is testable in a sane way. Think User interfaces. Think a driver for a space shuttle or a nuclear bomb (at least not with pure JUnit-tests ;) ). However, lots and lots of code is testable. Datastructures are. Algorithms are. Most Applicationlogic-classes are. So test it!

HTH. tetha

Answer (score 3):

> What exactly IS unit testing? Is it
>   built into code or run as separate
>   programs? Or something else?

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292197(VS.71).aspx): The primary goal of unit testing is to take the smallest piece of testable software in the application, isolate it from the remainder of the code, and determine whether it behaves exactly as you expect.

Essentially, you are writing small bits of code to test the individual bits of your code. In the .net world, you would run these small bits of code using something like NUnit or MBunit or even the built in testing tools in visual studio. In Java you might use JUnit. Essentially the test runners will build your project, load and execute the unit tests and then let you know if they pass or fail.

> How do you do it?

Well it's easier said than done to unit test. It takes quite a bit of practice to get good at it. You need to structure your code in a way that makes it easy to unit test to make your tests effective.

> When should it be done? Are there times or projects not to do it? Is
>   everything unit-testable?

You should do it where it makes sense. Not everything is suited to unit testing. For example UI code is very hard to unit test and you often get little benefit from doing so. Business Layer code however is often very suitable for tests and that is where most unit testing is focused.

Unit testing is a massive topic and to fully get an understanding of how it can best benefit you I'd recommend getting hold of a book on unit testing such as "[Test Driven Development by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)" which will give you a good grasp on the concepts and how you can apply them to your code.

Answer (score 2):

I find the easiest way to illustrate it is to look at some code. This getting started page on the NUnit site is a good introduction to the what and the how

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.5

Is everything testable? Generally if it calculates something then yes. UI code is a whole other problem to deal with though, as simulating users clicking on buttons is tricky.

What should you test? I tend to write tests around the things I know are going to be tricky. Complicated state transitions, business critical calculations, that sort of thing. Generally I'm not too worried about testing basic input/output stuff, although the purists will doubtless say I'm wrong on that front and *everything* should be tested. Like so many other things, there is no right answer!

Answer (score 2):

On the "How to do it" part:

I think the introduction to [ScalaTest](http://www.artima.com/scalatest/) does good job of illustrating different styles of unit tests.

On the "When to do it" part:

Unit testing is not only for testing. By doing unit testing you also force the design of the software into something that is unit testable. Many people are of the opinion that this design is for the most part Good Design(TM) regardless of other benefits from testing.

So one reason to do unit test is to force your design into something that hopefully will be easier to maintain that what it would be had you not designed it for unit testing.