# "section" at github: what does it mean?

Tags: node.js, github

Is it pull request or comment at pull or something else?

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/520f19fb0ef26d69f82488faa2eb3c11.png]

Comment: You mean what? The red rectangle or?

Comment: Coverage and Codestyle. Do you think it's just comments for pr?

Answer (score 1):

Coverage means "**[code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage)**": the amount of code covered by the unit-test cases.

As seen in [this issue](https://github.com/Shippable/support/issues/239#issuecomment-46865140), each GitHub project can chose to add as a comment to a PR any additional relevant information (like code coverage for instance).

Continuous Integration system, like for example [Travis-CI](http://docs.travis-ci.com/), can [process pull requests](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/), and add comments to them depending on the result of the build done by Travis.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](https://www.gregjs.com/javascript/2016/how-to-get-a-shiny-coverage-badge-for-your-github-project/) explains what coverage means in GitHub pretty well.
 Here is a section from the blog:

> Code coverage is a measure of how well you are testing your project. If a project has 99% coverage, that means that 99% of the lines, functions and/or branches of the files included in your tests are covered by tests. A line, function or branch is covered when said line, function or branch is executed in one or more of your tests.

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652292/what-is-unit-testing-and-how-do-you-do-it) if you want to know more about tests.