# Questions Regarding NUNIT Testing Tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I'm totally new to NUnit and have questions such as:

- What kind of testing does NUnit do?
- What problem does the tool solve?
- What are its star features?
- If I were to resort to another tool that's similar to NUnit: what should I use?

Comment: If you have to ask *"what problem does it solve?"* then maybe you should start by asking ["What is unit testing?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652292/what-is-unit-testing-and-how-do-you-do-it).

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki for more information on nUnit.  It is a unit testing framework what it tests is up to the test that you write.  I personally prefer xUnit.. but they both do the job.