# Finding the total number of odd intergers in the range

Tags: c++, range

If I want to find the total number of odd integers between a leftrange and a rightrange,  do you think this works ?

example leftrange = 3, rightrange = 8.

```
int FindOdd(int left, int right)
{
   bool lefteven  = (left  % 2) ? false: true;
   bool righteven = (right % 2) ? false: true;
   int length = (right-left) + 1;

   if (lefteven != righteven) //even length
   {
      return (length/2);
   }

   else //odd length
   {
      if (!lefteven)
          return ((length/2) + 1);

      else
          return (length/2);
   }
}
```

Comment: You tell us. Which values did you use to test? And what were the results of that test?

Comment: `bool lefteven  = (left  % 2) ? false: true;` --> `bool lefteven  = !(left  % 2);`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652292/what-is-unit-testing-and-how-do-you-do-it

Comment: If your code does work; I would suggest posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get further feedback.

Comment: I'd upvote an answer that uses metaprogramming: e.g. `foo<3, 8>::value`.

Comment: Here is a theoretical solution on Mathematics SE: [How do I determine the number of odd integers in a range?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138865/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-odd-integers-in-a-range). Wrap it into an algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

It's a clumsy way to do it. A better way is to use *integer division*:

```
unsigned FindOdd(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    return b / 2 - a / 2;
}
```

This will not include the final number if `b` is odd. I've cheekily changed the types to `unsigned` for the sake of elegance.