# Enzyme test nested component's method

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to use Enzyme to test a component's method. I know the typical way to do this is to use Enzyme's `instance()` method.

The thing is, this only work for `root` component and my component need to be wrapper in two Context provider to render (namely, react-router and apollo client).

```
  const wrapper = mount(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/login"]}>
        <AuthFormContainer />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
```

How can I test `methodA` of `AuthFormContainer` in that case ?

Comment: you should write a separate test case for the AuthFormContainer

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Can you elaborate on how to do that ?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I think we do need to test ApolloProvider if this component created by apollo team, because it was already tested. ThéoChampion if it is you custom component test it separately

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, but my component need to be wrapped by `apolloProvider` to be able to render (`authFormContainer` is a consumer)

Comment: @ThéoChampion, What I meant to say is that if you want to test the function within AuthFormContainer, you need to write test cases for that component instead of writing it for the component that renders ApolloProvider

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Writing tests for `AuthFormContainer` is what i'm trying to do here

Comment: can you show how your AuthFormContainer looks like and how have you written the tests

Answer (score 10):

For the unit testing, you should not be worried about the other components. But if you must, you may use the shallow rendering. Here is what I did:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/login"]}>
        <AuthFormContainer />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
);
```

Get the Component tree for the `AuthFormContainer` using:

```
const authFormControllerTree = wrapper.find(MemoryRouter).shallow().find(AuthFormContainer).shallow()
```

Now to test the `methodA` in the `AuthFormContainer`, you may just do:

```
authFormControllerTree.instance().methodA();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to `find(ApolloProvider).dive()` - and console.log it to see the tree inside.

Comment: if I do that, i get `TypeError: wrapper.find(...).dive is not a function`, any idea of what is going on ?

Comment: who is you wrapper?

Comment: can you find `wrapper.find(ApolloProvider)`?

Comment: Yes, this return me a `ReactWrapper { length: 1 }`

Comment: take a look to this one 
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html
probably you miss something.

Comment: `dive` method can be used only with shallow rendering which can't work for me as I'm obligated to wrap my component in contexts providers

Comment: In one case use shallow and in one use mount. Two separate test.

Comment: if I do `const wrapper = shallow(<AuthFormContainer />);` , then `console.log(wrapper.instance())` return `null`, any idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: try `const wrapper = shallow(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/login"]}>
        <AuthFormContainer />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );`

Comment: This return me the `ApolloProvider` ReactComponent instance

Comment: what about props  `find(ApolloProvider).props()`

Comment: Yes, this return me `ApolloProvider`'s props

Comment: Should I dig into `ApolloProvider` children's props to dive ? Seems a bit hacky

Comment: TypeError: wrapper.find(...).dive is not a function
If this is the error you are getting, then it might be because you are using `mount` instead of `shallow`.

Answer (score 0):

For React components you always write **Unit Tests**. According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/652382/2873331:

> Unit testing simply verifies that individual units of code (mostly functions) work as expected...

So here you should try to Test functionality of `AuthFormContainer` and not whether *react-router* and *apollo client* are injecting context correctly or not. Your test case should test: Given the `context` to the `AuthFormContainer`, do its instance methods work as expected or not.

To inject *context* you can use Enzyme's **shallow** method.

```
it('should work as expected', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(< AuthFormContainer />, {
        context: { ... }, // pass expected context here

    });
    wrapper.instance().method(); //extract the required method by using instance
    ...
  });
```

Reference: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html

On a side note, do not use `mount` unless you actually want to test things at DOM level. `mount` makes your tests very slow. Always prefer `shallow`.

Reference: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html

Answer (score 0):

Always test wrapper component differently than connected component. Export wrapper component and import to test file and test as you are doing but shallow ( I prefer)