# How to test child component method without Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to access and test a method of a child component in react using Jest. I am **not using Enzyme**, so this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765447/enzyme-test-nested-components-method) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245215/how-to-test-child-component-method-with-enzyme). I would like to use React Testing Library instead of Enzyme.

Earlier I was happily accessing the methods I needed to test like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

let container: any = null;
beforeEach(() => {
    // setup a DOM element as a render target
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    // cleanup on exiting
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
});

test("methodToTest should do what I want it to", () => {
    const { methodToTest } = render(<App />, container);
    methodToTest("some input");
    const output = document.querySelector(".outputFromMethod");
    expect(output.innerHTML).toBe("You gave me some input");
});
```

But now I need to wrap my `<App />` component in `withRouter()` from `react-router-dom`, so I have to do something like this: (Based on the [recipe suggested by React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router))

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

let container: any = null;
beforeEach(() => {
    // setup a DOM element as a render target
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    // cleanup on exiting
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
});

test("methodToTest should do what I want it to", () => {
    // THIS DOESN'T WORK NOW FOR GETTING methodToTest
    const { methodToTest } = render(<Router><App /></Router>, container);
    const output = document.querySelector(".outputFromMethod");
    expect(output.innerHTML).toBe("You gave me some input");
});
```

I understand that it's not ideal to try to test methods on a child component. But I need to do this because I have to have this component render inside of a `<Router>`. Is there any way to access the `<App />` components methods without using Enzyme, or using React Testing Library if necessary?

Comment: Have you already tried the `wrapper` approach?

Comment: @Jacob yes but it appears that methods from the component are not available when using the `render` from `@testing-library/react` (which has the `wrapper` option). I am asking about this here: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/492

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with Testing Library, that's against the [principles](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles). You're also using a strange style for testing. Have you tried to do this:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

test("methodToTest should do what I want it to", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Router><App /></Router>);
    expect(getByText("You gave me some input")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: Ok, I see that testing the method is against the principles. That makes sense, thank you. It would still be nice to be able to test the method of a component that was in a child (because I need to render it inside a `<Router>`), but I see now that it might be better practice to do something like this: https://www.polvara.me/posts/how-to-test-asynchronous-methods/

Comment: RTL has a different approach to tests. It doesn't test the method, it tests that the feature works—mainly by looking at DOM changes