# How to use a junit test to test connection

Tags: java, testing, junit

//    Trying to write a junit test for this. It's probably really obvious but i cannot think of a way to achieve it.

```
public void connectToDB() {
    conn = new QBasicConnection(host, port, user, password);
    try {
      conn.open();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("", e);
    } catch (QException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("", e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I would suggest you to read this post first:* *[What is unit testing and how do you do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652292/what-is-unit-testing-and-how-do-you-do-it)*

In your test-case you don´t want to open a real connection to the database.
This is not a part of your programm but part of the framework you are using to access the database functions.

*A good way to avoid this is to use mocks.
[What is Mocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking) gives you a good overview about mocks and why you should use them and not rely on the whole dependency of the DB connection.*

In fact, the only test you *could* write, would check your exception handling.
In the test you would check that the exception, thrown by `conn.open()` is handled correctly.

Comment: Yes this is great, thanks... I realized what i was trying to do. Thanks mate.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If this solved your problem you could flag it as answer.